# NodeJs, Crypto Error : "Error: error:0406B06E:rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_none:data too large for key size"

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptojs

I am getting error when I try to encrypt the data using crypto Module in nodejs.

I have tried disabling the padding also.

Error :Error: error:0406B06E:rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_none:data too large for key size

Code :-

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const privateKey = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIBVQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT8wggE7AgEAAkEAqPCzhHllwH/D1RWJ\noDso47Xe7N170rSBJPP7tC49wxf8OtR576SKlbHYmlbJmd2DtimNQkYhf1DbNA+G\ndlFn1QIDAQABAkEApidV58ydzp3aNRBhsz18Ebkl70BGMA1nlrh/rc5s4Bp1IeF5\nfM5iSTXcsMhzkBab8jgoFulffVhjhUOEdcZrAQIhANzM7CCymOhShScyWPfY0pP6\n08dVk5L2sTnYz2UG9MgtAiEAw99QK99gmZ8gd+7hvvlF/NG4GnI0U5lF/lXaUjPO\nf0kCIFUR1wAaD3OjJ44chc6oCSnef+3S+NKsnUeuUumXroPZAiEAu6BcscoGROHT\nPk+L2135Ftbl3h9r1HDMRXeD7J5HvlECIBcFryn4SxMuYS8xIFvq/viJmI7CL1Fh\nkeYmEpu8oxCS\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----';
let data = {
    "name": "anand",
    "Hi": "Hisdcsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"
};
let buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data));
let encrypted = crypto.privateEncrypt({
    key: privateKey,
    padding: crypto.constants.RSA_NO_PADDING
}, buffer);
console.log(encrypted.toString("base64"));
```

Comment: The message has a length of 96 bytes. The key only has a length of 64 bytes. For RSA the maximum message length is equal to the key length. And this only applies if there is _no_ padding. _With_ padding the maximum message length is _further reduced_ depending on the padding used. In this case with a key length of 64 bytes and without padding the maximum length is 64 bytes. Note that in practice, padding _must always_ be used for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco. So, What should I use to encrypt long messges? any suggestions

Comment: Nowadays, keys of [2048 bit or larger are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_size#Asymmetric_algorithm_key_lengths) used for RSA for security reasons. RSA is generally used to exchange symmetric keys (e.g. 32 bytes for AES-256). For longer texts, symmetric encryption (or [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) with regard to key exchange) is used.